# Are parahydrogen and orthohydrogen identical particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen, identical-particles

I have no formal physics background, just aerospace engineering, and I'm working on a DSMC project simulating relaxation of hydrogen in non-equilibrium, rarefied, 1D flow via translational and rotational energy only. My objective is to add orthohydrogen to a given simulation of parahydrogen.

For some reason, para-para and ortho-ortho collisions are fine, but ortho-para and para-ortho collisions yield a constant difference between total translational and total rotational energy at equilibrium. The error looks much like an imbalance in excitations and de-excitations. I suspect that the given para-simulated detailed balance (to calculate de-excitations) may work for para-para and ortho-ortho collisions, but not for ortho-para/para-ortho collisions.

I have been given a description and its corresponding equation:

> For identical particles the de-excitation collision cross section $\sigma_{ij\rightarrow i'j'}$ at $\varepsilon_1$ is related to excitation collision cross section $\sigma_{i'j'\rightarrow ij}$ at $\varepsilon_2$ by:
>
> [image]

If you can't see the image, then:

> $$\sigma_{ij\rightarrow i'j'}(\varepsilon_{1}) = \frac{ (1+\delta_{ij})(2i'+1)(2j'+1)\varepsilon_{2} } { (1+\delta_{i'j'})(2i+1)(2j+1)\varepsilon_1 } \cdot \sigma_{i'j'\rightarrow ij}(\varepsilon_2)$$
>
> Willauer, D. L., and Varghese P. L., “Direct Simulation of Rotational Relaxation Using State-to-State Cross Sections,” Journal of Thermophysics and Heat Transfer, Vol. 7, No. 1, 1993, pp. 49-54

According to this description, this equation only works for identical particles. Para-para works in simulation. Ortho-ortho works in simulation. Para-ortho doesn't. Perhaps para and ortho are not identical?

My question: Are parahydrogen and orthohydrogen identical particles? If not, how might I go about performing detailed balance on para- and ortho-hydrogen?

This is also my first question on StackExchange, ever, so please let me know if this question should go elsewhere, or if I'm not following etiquette properly.

TL;DR
Are parahydrogen and orthohydrogen identical particles? If not, how might I go about performing detailed balance on para- and ortho-hydrogen?

Comment: I have written your formulas using [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation). However, you may want to check them with the original image.

Comment: They seem non-identical to me.

Comment: Hint: parahydrogen is in a lower energy state than orthohydrogen.

Comment: I haven't actually been taught anything in quantum.. I'm assuming, "if they are at a different energy state, then they are non-identical"?